# How to fix my Ubuntu-sessions after a weird crash?

Tags: boot, 20.04, ethernet, amd-ryzen, gnome-session

In the recent days, I've had to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04.2 not once but twice, because of a weird crash. The computer works fine, and when I turn it on and off again, at first it behaves as expected. But as soon as I plug in an Ethernet cable and turn it on again, the startup screen cannot load anymore, and there's no amount of tinkering that will fix it. I know it's the ethernet that causes it, because it's happened twice in a row with two fresh Ubuntu installs.

When I boot up, I get a bunch of messages telling me there are “orphaned inodes.” It goes too fast for me to read it, and I don't know where the logfile is stored. Then comes the startup screen on tty1: it just shows a white cursor on a black screen. It appears to be stuck in a loop since my mouse will continually reload in the starting position every second or so.

My temporary fix is to go to tty2 and log in from there. Then I start the GUI with `startx`. However, I cannot start an Ubuntu session, or Ubuntu on Wayland as I used to. When I run the command `gnome-session` it simply fails with whatever session I choose.

I have tried reinstalling `gnome-session`, `gdm3`, nothing will do. I'm starting to get desperate and I certainly don't want to reinstall everything a third time. So I hope there is some solution I'm missing. For example, I don't know how to reinstall whatever program loads the startup screen.

Note however, that now the Ethernet works just fine. I just have to start a XWindow session manually every time I boot up, and I keep having a black screen of death on tty1 that sometimes makes my kernel crash if I switch to it.

Since this is important for these types of questions, I have a [HP Pavillon laptop Model 15-cw1905nz](https://support.hp.com/za-en/document/c06458585), with processor `AMD® Ryzen 7 3700u with radeon vega mobile gfx × 8` and GPU ```AMD® Raven``

Another thing that I can think of is that I had been using [`focalgdm3`](https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/focalgdm3) to change the background of my startup screen. Now when I run it, it doesn't seem to remember the changes I'd made.

I hope someone has any idea of what I could try next.

Comment: So is the problem caused simply by booting the system with an Ethernet cable connected? Also please give Ubuntu version and hw info.

Comment: I just now realized I'd forgotten to do that. Sorry, it should be fixed now.
The problem appears when I boot with an ethernet cable plugged in, but it persists afterwards and there is no way to fix it (f it was as simple as just unplugging the ethernet I wouldn't have had to reinstall Ubuntu twice). It seems really odd, I agree, but I've confirmed it twice.

Answer (score 0):

I just rebooted and the issue solved itself seemingly out of nowhere. The best explanation I've got is that I've tinkered with `focalgdm3` some more. Specifically, I set a new background for the startup screen—the old one had been removed, as explained in my question.

Now the startup screen loads just fine. I'mgoing to mark this question as solved, but I haven't even started to figure out what the problem was in the first place. Hopefully this is it.